# Modular redux best approach

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

What is currently the best approach to use redux in large, modular app?

I have app common part with state, layout, general providers etc. (as container) and modules, which are children, lazy load components.

I have some common part of state for whole app (i.e. auth,  events notifications, messages etc.) which should be avaiable in all modules.

Each module has a own state part, with own reducers, actions etc, which should be dynamically initialize (add or delete in root state depends on active module)

In previous projects i used redux-dynamic-modules, which works perfectly, but it's not mantained (last commit + 2 years ago).

I wonder if there is some actual better solution? (would be great if it works with redux-toolkit)

Thanks